# Hide select option based hour of the day

Tags: javascript, html, select

Is it possible to hide a form's select field based on the time of day?

[image]

Comment: You've got to at least attempt to write some code. The short answer is of course, yes. But try it yourself first.

Comment: You can give them each the same class, group them all in the same array, and then perform some operation with that. But thats beyond the scope of this question. Short answer is yes

Comment: write some code to help.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me =)

```js
var d = new Date();
    
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();   
   
   if(h==10){
     if(m<=30){
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     }
     else{
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     }

   }
   else if(h==11){
     if(m<=30){
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     
     }
     else{
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     }   
   }
   else if(h==12){
     if(m<=30){
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(6)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     
     }
     else{
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(7)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(6)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     }   
   }
   else if(h==13){
     if(m<=30){
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(8)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(6)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(7)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     
     }
     else{
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(9)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(6)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(7)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(8)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     }   
   }
   else if(h==14){
     if(m<=30){
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(10)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(6)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(7)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(8)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(9)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     
     }
     else{
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(11)').attr("selected",'selected');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(2)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(3)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(4)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(5)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(6)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(7)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(8)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(9)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(10)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
     }   
   }
   else if(h>=15){
   jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(10)').attr("disabled",'disabled');
   jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3').append("<option value='00'>Hoje acabou. Compre com agendamento amanhã.</option>");
   jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(1)').removeAttr("selected");
   jQuery('#order_wcj_checkout_field_3 option:nth-child(11)').attr("selected",'selected');
   }
```